# How to choose adequate size when choosing tensor size in NN?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, theano

I've created a NN to play a game (I'm using keras & python 3.6.x) and I'm trying to train it, but I'm having some difficulties with dimensions. I'm getting this error saying:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8

# In[ ]:


C:\Users\ganzs\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe "C:/Program Files/JetBrains/PycharmProjects/intercept/InterceptorNN.py"

Using TensorFlow backend.

WARNING (theano.configdefaults): g++ not available, if using conda: `conda install m2w64-toolchain`

C:\Users\ganzs\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\theano\configdefaults.py:560: UserWarning: DeprecationWarning: there is no c++ compiler.This is deprecated and with Theano 0.11 a c++ compiler will be mandatory
  warnings.warn("DeprecationWarning: there is no c++ compiler."

WARNING (theano.configdefaults): g++ not detected ! Theano will be unable to execute optimized C-implementations (for both CPU and GPU) and will default to Python implementations. Performance will be severely degraded. To remove this warning, set Theano flags cxx to an empty string.

WARNING (theano.tensor.blas): Using NumPy C-API based implementation for BLAS functions.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Program Files/JetBrains/PycharmProjects/intercept/InterceptorNN.py", line 195, in <module>
    network = train()
  File "C:/Program Files/JetBrains/PycharmProjects/intercept/InterceptorNN.py", line 100, in train
    loss = f_train(states, actions, rewards, newstates, discounts)
  File "C:\Users\ganzs\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\theano\compile\function_module.py", line 813, in __call__
    allow_downcast=s.allow_downcast)
  File "C:\Users\ganzs\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\theano\tensor\type.py", line 117, in filter
    data = theano._asarray(data, dtype=self.dtype)
  File "C:\Users\ganzs\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\theano\misc\safe_asarray.py", line 34, in _asarray
    rval = np.asarray(a, dtype=dtype, order=order)
  File "C:\Users\ganzs\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_asarray.py", line 85, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
ValueError: Bad input argument to theano function with name "C:/Program Files/JetBrains/PycharmProjects/intercept/InterceptorNN.py:67" at index 0 (0-based).  
Backtrace when that variable is created:

  File "C:/Program Files/JetBrains/PycharmProjects/intercept/InterceptorNN.py", line 195, in <module>
    network = train()
  File "C:/Program Files/JetBrains/PycharmProjects/intercept/InterceptorNN.py", line 29, in train
    STATE = theano.tensor.tensor4()
setting an array element with a sequence.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I'm trying to initialize STATE, that's why I don't understand how could I be setting an array element if STATE is declared for the first time.

Here's [my code repo](https://github.com/ElinorG11/Intrcpt).

Comment: Can you include a copy paste of the actual traceback? This does not look like a real one.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro thank for the replay. I've edited the quetsion with the full traceback